# SQL Server 2017 relative path issue

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2016, sql-server-2017

Encountered interesting problem after migrating to SQL Server 2017.

**Absolute path test**

```
backup database master to disk = 'C:\Temp\1\2\3\master.bak'
```

Backup is created in C:\Temp\1\2\3\ as expected.

**Relative path test #1**

```
backup database master to disk = 'C:\Temp\1\2\3\..\master.bak'
```

Backup is created in C:\Temp\

Expected: C:\Temp\1\2\

**Relative path test #2**

```
backup database master to disk = 'C:\Temp\11\22\33\..\master.bak'
backup database master to disk = 'C:\Temp\111\222\333\..\master.bak'
backup database master to disk = 'C:\Temp\bin\bin\bin\..\master.bak'
```

Backups are created in folders C:\Temp\11\, C:\Temp\111\, C:\Temp\bin\

Expected: C:\Temp\11\22\, C:\Temp\111\222\ and C:\Temp\bin\bin\ respectively.

**Relative path test #3**

```
backup database master to disk = 'C:\Temp\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\..\master.bak'
backup database master to disk = 'C:\Temp\1111\2222\3333\..\master.bak'
```

Backups are created in folders C:\Temp\Folder1\Folder2 and C:\Temp\1111\2222 respectively as expected.

As you can see, all relative paths have the same depth, but depending on folder names lengths the backup file lands on different levels.
I wasn't able to replicate this issue with SQL Server 2014.
I was able to replicate this issue both in SQL Server 2017 RTM and RTM-CU2.

OS: Windows Server 2016. Paths are resolved correctly when pasted to Windows Explorer.

How do I make relative paths work when they contains short (under 4 characters) folder names?

Comment: interesting, voted up

Comment: I'd post this to the microsoft page as it may be a bug

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be fixed in SQL Server 2017 CU14 (or maybe earlier).

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed on "Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)"

This is a bug!  However, after playing around with it I found a workaround by adding another dot after the directory names.

```
backup database master to disk = 'C:\Temp\1.\2.\3.\..\master.bak'
```

This successfully backed up to 'C:\Temp\1\2\'.  I've found no reference why this works.  Also, it would probably a good idea to stay away from low character directories if possible.

Comment: Fighting bugs with more bugs?